# Websphere Cobra.NoResponse Request Timed Out

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, jrules, ibm-was, ibm-odm

I am getting the below error (in SystemOut.log in Decision Center) exactly 5 minutes after firing our rules, it’s been consistently 5 minutes. The ruleset is getting sent from Decision Center to Decision Server, because I can see the rules in Decision Server.

```
VVV -- Project name :RTE Placement Determination---- VVVVV
[9/26/14 12:42:25:725 CDT] 0000008d Builder       I   Use of the Rule Common Engine...
[9/26/14 12:42:32:314 CDT] 0000008d IlrRulesetArc I   Ruleset archive built [6567ms]
[9/26/14 12:42:32:314 CDT] 0000008d IlrRulesetArc I   -------------------------------
[9/26/14 12:42:32:314 CDT] 0000008d IlrRulesetArc I   Checking ruleset archive (rule analysis enabled)...
[9/26/14 12:42:37:714 CDT] 0000008d IlrRulesetArc I   -------------------------------
[9/26/14 12:42:37:718 CDT] 0000008d IlrRulesetArc I   ====> Overall time: 11971ms
[9/26/14 12:42:39:040 CDT] 00000092 SystemOut     O RuleApp name: RTEPlacementDeterminationCOSMETICSRulesApp
Versioning policy: replace_ruleApp_key
Rule Execution Server: http://odmdslp01.ch3.prod.i.com:9080/res
Operations:
/RTEPlacementDeterminationCOSMETICSRulesApp/1.0 -> /RTEPlacementDeterminationCOSMETICSRulesApp/1.0: Replace the existing element
/RTEPlacementDeterminationCOSMETICSRulesApp/1.0/RTEPlacementDetermination/1.0 -> /RTEPlacementDeterminationCOSMETICSRulesApp/1.0/RTEPlacementDetermination/1.0: Element added
[9/26/14 12:44:55:276 CDT] 000000a2 SelectionMana W   WWLM0061W: An error was encountered sending a request to cluster member {CELLNAME=DevCell01, MEMBERNAME=DSNode01-DSServer, NODENAME=DSNode01} and that member has been marked unusable for future requests to the cluster "", because of exception: org.omg.CORBA.NO_RESPONSE: Request 138 timed out  vmcid: IBM  minor code: B01 completed: Maybe
        at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.getCallStream(Connection.java:2423)
```

The following is the error I am getting in SystemErr.log in Decision Center:

```
9/26/14 12:44:55:279 CDT] 000000a2 SystemErr     R java.rmi.RemoteException: CORBA NO_RESPONSE 0x4942fb01 Maybe; nested exception is:
        org.omg.CORBA.NO_RESPONSE: Request 138 timed out  vmcid: IBM  minor code: B01 completed: Maybe
```

Both Decision Server's and Decision Center's ORB Service parameters are the following:
-Request Timeout: 300 seconds
-Locate Request Timeout: 300 seconds
-The Thread Pool Settings is Use Thread Pool Settings directly associated with the ORB service

Decision Center's Transaction Service parameters are the following:
-Total transaction lifetime timeout: 300 seconds
-Aysnc response timeout: 30 seconds
-Client inactivity timeout: 60 seconds
-Maximum transaction timeout: 300 seconds

Decision Server's Transaction Service parameters are the following:
-Total transaction lifetime timeout: 5000 seconds
-Aysnc response timeout: 30 seconds
-Client inactivity timeout: 120 seconds
-Maximum transaction timeout: 900 seconds

How do I resolve this? Thank you!

Comment: I see that this is tagged with websphere-mq but I don't see any details in the question about MQ. MQ has various 5 minute time outs too. If there is MQ in this setup can you add the details to the question?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, it's not websphere mq, it's Websphere Application Server v. 8.5.

Answer (score 0):

1. Start the administrative console. To do this, open a Web browser, and 
   enter http://yourNodeHost:yourAdminConsolePort/ibm/conso le in the address 
   bar.
2. Navigate to *Servers > Application Servers > yourAdminServer > 
   Container Services > Transaction Service*.
3. Increase the maximum transaction timeout value to z seconds. * If i 
   remember correctly this should be set to 0 so that the transaction never 
   times out*
4. Recycle your administration server to make the new setting effective.